# re.sub with a .group() - Unable to replace in python

Tags: python

With Python, I am trying to use re.sub to replace some items in svg_text

**Expected Output:**
Substitute  RoundShapes_group_match.group() with classes_removed_text in svg_text

**Actual Output:**
svg_text stays the same -- RoundShapes_group_match.group() remains unchanged

Here is the code.
I know people suggest lxml but I can't get that to work either and would still like to figure out why the re.sub isn't working.

I think it has to do with the **RoundShapes_group_match.group()** because even if I try to replace with ' ' instead of classes_removed_text it doesn't work.

**Question:**

1. Is re.sub not able to find a .group() or .group(0) string?

My python spacing is correct, and it is not throwing errors... it doesn't look correct on Stack Overflow though...

```py
import re

def remove_RoundShapes_group_classes(svg_text):
    """
    Within <g id="RoundShapes"> and before SquareShapes, remove all path class names.  Do not modify class names
    in other groups outside of RoundShapes.
    """
    # RoundShapes_group_match = re.search(r"""<g\s+id\s*=\s*"\S*?RoundShapes.*?</g>""", svg_text, flags=re.I | re.DOTALL)
    # Change to SquareShapes to search to next group
    RoundShapes_group_match = re.search(r"""<g\s+id\s*=\s*"\S*?RoundShapes.*?SquareShapes""", svg_text,
                                        flags=re.I | re.DOTALL)
    
    if RoundShapes_group_match is None:
        print("Could not find the RoundShapes group.", file=stderr)
        return svg_text
    
    classes_removed_text = re.sub(r'''class\s*=\s*".*?"''', '', RoundShapes_group_match.group(), flags=re.I)
    # print(classes_removed_text)
    
    RoundShapes_to_replace = (RoundShapes_group_match.group(0))
    
    ##RoundShapes_group_match.group() is what is not working.  Are there extra returns?
    svg_text = re.sub(RoundShapes_group_match.group(), classes_removed_text, svg_text, 1)
    return svg_text
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input ? And the expected output ? Also, did you mean to use a capital S in the `RoundShapes_group_match` regex ? (`'s' != 'S'`)

Comment: Thanks -- Yes when I print RoundShapes_group_match.group() or classes_removed_text, the print has the expected output.  It's a problem with the re.sub not finding the RoundShapes_group_match.group().  Even when I try to replace it with '', the re.sub does not work.

Comment: I'd like to help you out, but without an example of the input and the expected output, I can't reproduce your issue to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this resolved the issue,
but instead of using re.sub I used replace

```
svg_text = svg_text.replace(RoundShapes_group_match.group(0), classes_removed_text)
return svg_text
```

It now works!